# Don’t start container unless subfolders exist

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to not start a container and/or stop a container if a folder on the host or within my docker-compose exists?
I use docker to mount my rclone drive and meegerfs. I’d like to not start mergerfs unless it sees either subfolders in /mnt/cloud on the host or /cloud in the container which I have set at /mnt/cloud:/cloud mounts for rclone.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the command you need to run on startup, you can do something like this in your `CMD` statement in your Dockerfile

```
CMD [ -d /cloud ] && echo "/cloud exists" || echo "/cloud does not exist"
```

You can then replace each `echo` command with whatever you want to happen when the `/cloud` directory exists or doesn't exist.

Comment: Dockerfile would apply if this was my docker image rather than a remote container image in my docker-compose, no?

Comment: Depending on how the image works, you might be able to use the same command in a `command:` in docker-compose.